# Grails Spring Security get user by id

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm writing Grails application with Spring Security plugin.

I have enabled queries generated by GORM into console and I have noticed that every request Security query the database about users, selecting them by it's username.

My intention is load user's by it's ID's, not usernames for increase performance.

I am aware that there is a possibility to overwrite `UserDetailsService` method `loadUserByUsername(String username)`, but this method is used both for refreshing user's credential during the session and in login form, where in fact I want to authenticate user by it's username.

I have three questions:

1. How to load user by id? Should I inject user ID instead of username in `GrailsUser` (implementation of `UserDetails`) instead of regular username and use `long selectById = Long.valueOf(String username)`?
2. How to create different user provider for refreshing session to grab user by ID and different for user login (when I want to grab user by it's username/email)?
3. There is possibility to fetch user credentials not every request, but every X seconds?

Comment: @Gregg, it is truism, that Int PK will be faster. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i managed to solve this problem. The queries are generated by:

`springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`

Unfortunatelly, this method fetches User model class by username (from Principal object) and maps it into database field, at most configured by:

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName`

as mentioned [in documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#domainClassProperties).

I have tried

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'id'`

but i received class-cast exception from String to Long.

Workaround is simple - create own Principle with `username` field typed as Long.

See `PrincipalProxy` in my solution:

```
package com.selly.util.security

import java.security.Principal;

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

class AppMetadataAuthenticationToken implements Authentication, Principal {

    private boolean authenticated
    private GrailsUser userDetails
    private Principal principal

    public AppMetadataAuthenticationToken(GrailsUser userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails
        this.principal = new PrincipalProxy(userDetails)
    }

    public GrailsUser getUser() {
        return userDetails
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userDetails.getUsername()
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return userDetails.getUsername()
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return userDetails.getAuthorities()
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return userDetails.password
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return getUser()
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return principal
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authenticated
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.authenticated = authenticated
    }

    static class PrincipalProxy implements Principal {

        GrailsUser grailsUser
        Long username

        public PrincipalProxy(GrailsUser grailsUser) {
            this.grailsUser = grailsUser
            this.username = grailsUser.id
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return grailsUser.id
        }
    }
}
```

To return this Token, just register your own `AuthenticationProvider`:

```
package com.selly.util.security;

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException

public class AppUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        def token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication

        def user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.principal)

        if(!user)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Cannot find user", authentication.principal)

        if(!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, authentication.credentials, null))
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password")

        return new AppMetadataAuthenticationToken(user)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

}


package com.selly.util.security;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException

public class AppMetadataAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return AppMetadataAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

}
```

Register it in `resources.groovy`

```
appUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider(AppUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider) {
    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
    passwordEncoder = ref('passwordEncoder')
    userCache = ref('userCache')
    saltSource = ref('saltSource')
    preAuthenticationChecks = ref('preAuthenticationChecks')
    postAuthenticationChecks = ref('postAuthenticationChecks')
    springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
}
```

And in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
    'appMetadataAuthenticationProvider',
    'appUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider',
//  'daoAuthenticationProvider',
//  'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
//  'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]
```

Now all works perfectly:

`Hibernate: select this_.id as id13_0_, this_.account_expired as account2_13_0_, this_.account_locked as account3_13_0_, this_.enabled as enabled13_0_, this_."password" as password5_13_0_, this_.password_expired as password6_13_0_, this_.username as username13_0_, this_.workspace as workspace13_0_ from users this_ where (**this_.id=?**) limit ?`

Instead of using `getCurrentUser()` you can also `getPrincipal()` and cast to your previously populated object with more data than `Principal` interface offers.